# Error when trying to format dates using an array,PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, datetime

I have an array of dates to which I would like to give the format 'Y-m-d', however when I try, I get the error

"Call a member function format () on array"

What I have done before is to pass two dates to a function that returns the time intervals, for example, if I give the following two dates:

```
2017-06-05 | 2017-06-10
```

This function returns me in Y-m-d format

```
"2017-06-06,2017-06-07,2017-06-08 ...
```

I previously had no problems formatting the result, however, now that I have sent an array it has stopped working, this is my code

```
      public function testArray(Request $request)
          {
            if ($request!="" && $request->idUser!="") 
            {
             $timeslot= new Timeslot;
             $idUser=$request->idUser;
             $fecha1=$request->fecha2;//array
             $fecha2=$request->fecha1;//array

             $slotD=$request->slotH;//array
             $i=0;
             $k=0;
             $j=0; 
             foreach ($fecha1 as $key => $value) {
                $date1[$k]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
              $k++;
             }
             foreach ($fecha2 as $key => $value) {
               $date2[$i]=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
              $i++;
             }


             foreach ($slotD as $key => $value) {
                $value=str_replace("minutos","minutes",$value);
                $slot[$j]=$value;
               $j++;
             }

             $array=array("fechaInicio"=>$date1,"fechaFin"=>$date2,"slot"=>$slot);

             for($l=0;$l<count($date1);$l++)
             {
              $datePeriod["periodo"][]=$timeslot->returnDates($date1[$l],$date2[$l]);//this method give me an array with date intervals
                }
             $dates=array();
             $m=0;

             foreach ($datePeriod as $key => $value)
              {

                $dates[$m][$key]=$value->format('Y-m-d');//ERROR

                $m++;

              }







          }

           return $dates; 
          }
```

The function returnDates is this

```
function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
                    $fromdate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fromdate);
                    $todate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $todate);
                    return new   DatePeriod(
                        $fromdate,
                        new  DateInterval('P1D'),
                        $todate->modify('+1 day')
                    );
                }
```

When I use the variable $ datePeriod as a common variable, I get the result that I want

```
for($l=0;$l<count($date1);$l++)
   {
    $datePeriod=$timeslot->returnDates($date1[$l],$date2[$l]);
      }




Result:
    [["2017-06-17"],{"1":"2017-06-18"},{"2":"2017-06-19"},{"3":"2017-06-20"},{"4":"2017-06-21"}]
```

The problem appears when I convert the variable into an associative array, what could I do in this case?

This is the array that I get if I did not format the dates

```
[{"periodo":[{"start":{"date":"2017-06-17 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"current":null,"end":{"date":"2017-06-22 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"interval":{"y":0,`"m":0,"d":1,"h":0,"i":0,"s":0,"weekday":0,"weekday_behavior":0,"first_last_day_of":0,"invert":0,"days":false,"special_type":0,"special_amount":0,"have_weekday_relative":0,"have_special_relative":0},"recurrences":1,"include_start_date":true}
        ,{"start":{"date":"2017-06-17 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"current":null,"end":{"date":"2017-06-22 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"interval":{"y":0,"m":0,"d":1,"h":0,"i":0,"s":0,"weekday":0,"weekday_behavior":0,"first_last_day_of":0,"invert":0,"days":false,"special_type":0,"special_amount":0,"have_weekday_relative":0,"have_special_relative":0},"recurrences":1,"include_start_date":true},{"start":{"date":"2017-06-17 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"current":null,"end":{"date":"2017-06-22 18:20:35.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"interval":{"y":0,"m":0,"d":1,"h":0,"i":0,"s":0,"weekday":0,"weekday_behavior":0,"first_last_day_of":0,"invert":0,"days":false,"special_type":0,"special_amount":0,"have_weekday_relative":0,"have_special_relative":0},"recurrences":1,"include_start_date":true}]}]
```

*Update

this is the code of my timeslot class

```
<?php
            namespace App;

            use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
            use DateTime;
            use DatePeriod;
            use DateInterval;
            use DB;
            class TimeSlot extends Model
            {
                protected $table = 'timeslots';
                public $timestamps = false;

            function sumarFechas($times) {
                $minutes=0;
                // loop throught all the times
                foreach ($times as $time) {
                    list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
                    $minutes += $hour * 60;
                    $minutes += $minute;
                }

                $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
                $minutes -= $hours * 60;

                // returns the time already formatted
                return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);
            }



            function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
                $fromdate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fromdate);
                $todate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $todate);
                return new   DatePeriod(
                    $fromdate,
                    new  DateInterval('P1D'),
                    $todate->modify('+1 day')
                );
            }

            function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
                $fromdate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fromdate);
                $todate =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $todate);
                return new   DatePeriod(
                    $fromdate,
                    new  DateInterval('P1D'),
                    $todate->modify('+1 day')
                );
            }


            function getDispo()
            {
                $date=$this->select('slot_date')
                ->where('user_id','=',$this->user_id)
                ->groupBy('slot_date')
                ->get();

                return $date;

            }

            function getHoras()
            {
                $date=$this->select('slot_date','inicio','fin')
                ->where('user_id','=',$this->user_id)
                ->get();

                return $date;

            }

            function getHorasId()
            {
                $date=$this->select('id','slot_date','inicio','fin','slot_status')
                ->where('user_id','=',$this->user_id)
                ->where('slot_date','=',$this->fechaD)
                ->orderBy(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE(`inicio`, '%l:%i %p')"))
                ->get();

                return $date;

            }

            }
```

Comment: What's the output when you remove `->format('Y-m-d')` from `$value->format('Y-m-d');`?

Comment: hi @jrn , the response is  something like this `[[{"date":"2017-06-17 18:09:58.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}],{"1":{"date":"2017-06-18 18:09:58.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}},{"2":{"date":"2017-06-19 18:09:58.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}},{"3":{"date":"2017-06-20 18:09:58.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}},{"4":{"date":"2017-06-21 18:09:58.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}]`

Comment: What does class Timeslot look like?

Comment: Hi @jrn , I've updated my question

Comment: You have function returnDates() twice in class Timeslot.

Comment: It is true hehe, I am surprised that laravel has not warned me about that error, even so the error continues, I suspect it may be the object returned by that function, when I save it in an array, its contents change to when I store it in a variable normal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146790/discussion-between-jrn-and-felipe-castillo).

Comment: In your foreach loop, shouldn't you be using `$datePeriod["periodo"]`? :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `$value` is not an instance of object `DateTime`.
Try replacing this line:

```
$dates[$m][$key]=$value->format('Y-m-d');//ERROR
```

with these two:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($value);
$dates[$m][$key]=date('Y-m-d',$timestamp);//NO ERROR? :-)
```

You can also combine it into one line:

```
$dates[$m][$key]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value));//NO ERROR? :-)
```

Comment: Changing the code returns the error ´date() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given´

Comment: The problem is in the variable is an array, I tried the way you told me and returned the error, `strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Answer (score 0):

formatting the date before parsing it should do the trick

```
 $value['date'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value['date']));
 $dates[$m][$key]=$value;
//This returns the array with the date formatted
```

**OR**

```
 $dates[$m][$key]=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($value['date']));
//This returns just the formatted dates
```